# jQuery load missing argument

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-load

I have code like this

```
function firstload(maxid, next_page, results, animation_image, btn_load, url, endpoint) {
        var a = ''+maxid+'';
        var b = ''+next_page+'';
        var c = ''+endpoint+'';

        $('#'+results+'').load('<?php echo base_url()?>create/firstload', { max_id: a, next_page: b, endpoint: c }, function() { 
            var nextpage = $('#'+next_page+'').val();
            if (nextpage != 0) { $('.'+btn_load+'').show(); }
            else {  $('.'+btn_load+'').hide();  }
            $('.'+animation_image+'').hide();
        });
    }

firstload('max_id','nextpage','results','animation_image','load_more','load','get_user_recent');
```

and php backend like this :

```
function firstload($max_id, $next_page, $endpoint) {
 echo '<p> '$max_id' </p> //just a piece of code
}
```

[EDIT] I add some code on the function. 
i want id #result at frontend contain 'max id' from firstload function.

But it is returning some error :

```
Severity: Warning
Message: Missing argument 1 for Create::firstload()
Filename: controllers/Create.php
Line Number: 156
```

and it happened to argument 2 and 3 too.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you see when you look at the network request?

Comment: This is a PHP error - you need to make sure you have all the parameters in the call.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework? How are the arguments expected to be passed to the `firstload` function in the `Create` controller?

Comment: `load()` will `post` your data when an object is passed to it. I suspect you aren't expecting a post at server

Comment: Line number : 156 is "function firstload($max_id, $next_page, $endpoint)". So i think the variable from front-end didn't pass to back-end.

Comment: Do you have routes set up?

Comment: There isn't enough known about how your php function should work or what framework you are using

Comment: im using codeigniter

Comment: well then you need to receive post instead of get , or modify url of `load()`. The url you are sending from `load()` does not match what codeigniter expects

Comment: all : finally i'm using $.post and it works. thanks for help! :))

Answer (score -3):

Place `<?php ?>` tags around your code that you want to run as php. It looks like you are missing these tags around you call to `firstload(...)`

Comment: you are confusing a javascript method of same name with php method